# I want to Redirect on Click and then Change Button Text, How do I do that?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am building a web page, I have a submit button, onclick I want to redirect the user and then change the text of the button to Thank You.

Basically it redirects to the same page but I am using a PHP click to count clicks filtering the IP so it generates it's own links with Div ID

hence when the user clicks on the button, he returns to the same page but the button text is changed to Thank You.

```
 HTML
 <div class="voteBtnBox"><!--voteBtnBox start-->
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Vote" id="voteBtn" onclick="showDiv()" />

 </div><!--voteBtnBox end-->

 JS      
 window.location.href = 'http://localhost/aaa/counter/click.php?id=roy';
```

Comment: After redirecting, how can you see the button ?

Comment: what have u tried so far

Comment: Can you please paste your html here?? you can edit you question and paste your html then I will provide you solution!

Comment: you need to make a diferent button and hide the previous,you save a submit value in a session and based on that sesion you show the  thank you button and hide the submit button

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen Actually it redirects to the same page

Comment: @soul I had tried the JS onclick() to redirect but I cant figure out how to change the button text

Comment: @liffi I have added the HTML

Comment: @advait I have added my answer try that now ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following now.

```
 <?php $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
 $uri = explode('#', $url); ?>
 <div class="voteBtnBox"><!--voteBtnBox start-->
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php if(count($uri) > 1){ echo 'Thank You'; }else{ echo 'Vote';} ?>" id="voteBtn" onclick="showDiv()" />

 </div><!--voteBtnBox end-->

<script> 
function showDiv(){    
   window.location.href = 'http://localhost/aaa/counter/click.php?id=roy';
}
</script>
```

Comment: your page is php page or html ??

Comment: Ahh ok than php code will not work. Is this possible that you can change the page from html to php. your page html will remain same as it is. nothing will be broken. ??

Comment: I changed it to PHP, it seems to be working but when clicked it still shows Vote, which div should that $_GET['id'] match with?

Comment: It must need to be work, anyway can you please change $_GET['id'] to $_REQUEST['id'] and then test once again. Make sure it will redirect to specified url and the following id=roy exists in the url.

Comment: Actually this url 'http://localhost/aaa/counter/click.php?id=roy' redirects to 'http://localhost/aaa/popsong.php#roy' to record clicks, and that's the reason why I guess this isn't working

Comment: Why this is changed from id=roy to #roy even we using the window.location.href = 'http://localhost/aaa/counter/click.php?id=roy'; for redirecting. ??

Comment: ahh I think its making the SEO url's right?? than you can also try another solution I have .. Let me know if you need ..

Comment: actually I was using a script to count clicks and display in backend, college voting, so it generates link and that link redirects back to the main thing, so how can I make it work now, I mean the button to thank you.

Comment: After redirecting if your url like 'localhost/aaa/popsong.php#roy' than I have update my answer. Try the new code now

Comment: can you give me the other solution?

Comment: Ahh replace HTTP_REFERER  with REQUEST_URI.

Comment: Ahh replace HTTP_REFERER  with REQUEST_URI. I have tested REQUEST_URI will work for us ..

Answer (score 0):

May be you could try something like this:

```
<input type='submit' value='<?php ($_REQUEST["SOME_PARAM_NAME"].length != 0 ) ? echo "Thank You": echo "Submit"; ?>'>
```

Comment: Can you help with the PHP request